# Schedule Speed Tests

Tags: python, speed-test

I want a way to test our network speed every 10 mins automatically and record the output, I found this python https://pypi.python.org/pypi/speedtest-cli and wanted to know if there is a way I could make a program that will run the command sleep for a few mins and then run it again capturing the output every time and logging it into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to run a cronjob with also the date as name of the log file so after that you can analyse the logs.

Python logging:
[python logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

You can also use greylog for logging in python, its simple and very useful:
[greylog](http://www.graylog2.org/)

Cronjob with date:
[Cronjob](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Unix/UNIX_7.shtml)

Comment: I think I will use the cron job idea and edit the original program to write it to a file

Comment: Well my suggestion is to use cronjob instead of running the program all the time in sleep.